# How to index Col1 +'|' + Col2 for fastest search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem have a very slow query with this search

```
Select * 
  From table1
Where 
  Col1 +'|' + Col2 Not IN 
  (Select Col1 +'|' + Col2 from table1 Where tabl1.condition2 = true)
Where tabl1.condition1 = true
```

The table1 is same in both inner and outer query. But as we dont have index on both columns with '|' so its too slow. How can I create index on Col1+'|'Col2 or if there is any other solution which works faster.

ok adding almost original query

## Problem SQL

```
Select * 
FROM tblRawPos 
WHERE  
  Source = 'SRC' 
  AND Cust = 'CST' 
  AND NOT CustAcct+'|'+tblRawPos.Cusip IN (SELECT CustAcct+'|'+Cusip FROM tblRawPos WHERE Source = 'CST' AND Custodian = 'CST'  )
  AND NOT Account+'|'+tblRawPos.Cusip IN (SELECT Account+'|'+Cusip FROM tblRawPos WHERE Source = 'CST' AND Custodian = 'CST' )
```

## Changed according to proposed solution (still slow)

```
Select R.* 
FROM tblRawPos R 
WHERE  
  R.Source = 'SRC' 
  AND R.Cust = 'CST' 
  AND Not Exists (SELECT 1 FROM tblRawPos RR WHERE RR.Source = 'SRC' 
                        AND RR.Cust = 'CST' 
                        AND (
                            ( RR.CustAcct + '|' + RR.Cusip = R.CustAcct + '|' + R.Cusip) OR (RR.Account + '|' + RR.Cusip = R.Account + '|' + R.Cusip)
                            )
                        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Try using join:

```
Select a.* 
FROM (
select * 
from tblRawPos
where Source = 'SRC' AND Cust = 'CST'
) a
left join 
(
select CustAcct, Account, Cusip  
from tblRawPos
where Source = 'CST' AND Custodian = 'CST'
) b on (a.CustAcct = b.CustAcct and a.Cusip = b.Cusip) or (a.Account = b.Account and a.Cusip = b.Cusip)
where b.source is null;
```

`Join` performs better than `in` statement, and the `where` condition reduces the size of "b" table which should improve the efficiency as well.

Comment: I agree with you but here there are two conditions, please look again at the "Problem" SQL in my question, I must use Acct+'|'+Cusip field col.

Comment: @Ammad Okay I have updated my query to fit your data, hope that works. We use `(a.CustAcct = b.CustAcct and a.Cusip = b.Cusip) or (a.Account = b.Account and a.Cusip = b.Cusip)` here. Note that `a.CustAcct = b.CustAcct and a.Cusip = b.Cusip` is equivalent to `a.CustAcct|a.Cusip = b.CustAcct|b.Cusip`.

Comment: thanks @Larry, one of my fellow at work, also gave me such idea, now testing with number of rows with raw query if both matches, means your idea will be accepted.

Comment: After careful review the results I found that your solution works and I am accepting it. Thanks @Larry Li.

Answer (score 7):

I assume the expression `co1 + '|' + col2` is simply to combine the two columns into a single column -- and not to equate "A|B"/"C" with "A"/"B|C".

Do not use `NOT IN` with a subquery.  It does not do what you expect when any of the returned values are `NULL`.  Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select t1.* 
From table1 t1
Where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.col1 = t1.col2 and tt1.col2 = t1.col2 and <some condition>
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(col1, col2)`.  You can add other columns used for the additional conditions as additional columns.

An alternative that might be even faster is a window function:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             sum(case when <conditions> then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col1, col2) as cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where cnt = 0;
```

I strongly doubt that you need an index on `co1 + '|' + col2`, but you can create one with a computed column:

```
alter table table1 add col_1_2 as (co1 + '|' + col2) persisted;

create index idx_table1_col_1_2 on table1(col_1_2);
```

You then need to use that column in the code:

```
Select t1.* 
From table1 t1
Where not exists (select 1 from table1 tt1 where tt1.col_1_2 = t1.col_1_2 and . . .);
```

I strongly recommend the first two approaches, though.

Comment: But I cannot miss Col1 + '|' + Col2 combination as it could be a business rule. Its a very old code and I cannot change much in Query.

Comment: @Ammad . . . I'm not sure what the point of your comment is.  It is very, very, very likely that the only purpose of that expression is to combine the two columns into a single expression so `not in` can be used.  This is not necessary with `not exists`.

Comment: You are correct but my question is how to create such index on co1 + '|' + col2. Can you explain your computed column idea as well.

Comment: @Ammad . . . "or if there is any other solution which works faster."  The first two solutions would generally be more appropriate.

Comment: This application is in prod and cannot add a calculated column, too many restrictions. So only SQL change or index could be the point.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, your solutions were amazing and I learned the new ways to achieve my targets in different SQL scenarios, I will definitely using those in my other SQL problems but for particularly current question, the other solution perfectly fits and I got the result. Many thanks for your help and comments.

Comment: @Ammad . . . You are using a join instead of the solutions here; strange choice.  The window function is probably the best approach.

Comment: Yes @Gordon, that window function is still not clear to me how to fit into my situation, if you can show me by converting my query into window solution it would be nice for me and others too. :)

Comment: @Ammad . . . That is the second solution in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Such questions usually arise, when the combination of two fields must be unique. E.g. a model number and a serial number:

```
model_no | serial_no | combined
12-3     | 4-567     | 12-3-4-567
12-34    | 567       | 12-3-4-567
```

Your usage of the pipe character, however, makes it unlikely that you are dealing with such a case. It rather seems you would want to look for the same accout and IP as in

```
WHERE (CustAcct, Cusip) NOT IN (SELECT CustAcct, Cusip FROM tblRawPos WHERE ...)
```

which SQL Server does not allow. (Some other DBMS do.)

So use `EXISTS` instead:

```
Select * 
FROM tblRawPos rp
WHERE Source = 'SRC' 
AND Cust = 'CST' 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tblRawPos other
  WHERE other.Cusip = rp.Cusip
  AND (other.CustAcct = rp.CustAcct OR other.Account = rp.Account)
  AND other.Source = 'CST'
  AND other.Custodian = 'CST' 
);
```

You should have at least the following index for this:

```
create index idx on tblRawPos (Cusip, Source, Custodian);
```

Even better would be a covering index:

```
create index idx1 on tblRawPos (Cusip, Source, Custodian, Account, CustAcct);
```

You should also try additional indexes starting with `Source` and `Custodian`:

```
create index idx2 on tblRawPos (Source, Custodian, Cusip, Account, CustAcct);
create index idx3 on tblRawPos (Custodian, Source, Cusip, Account, CustAcct);
```

You can try other variations. Changed order. Less columns. At last check the execution plan which of these indexes get used by the DBMS and drop the others.